# Conditionally change object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm changing object property based on condition. I'm using react
Let's say an object:

```
obj = {a: 4, b: 6, ...}
```

Now I want to change `obj.a` if **flag is true** so I can do something like below:

```
setState({...obj, a: flag === true ? 6 : obj.a})
```

Is there any other way to do it, I don't want to use ternary operator like above because in the nested object it looks nasty.

I also don't want to copy the object and change it like below:

```
 const obj_copy = {...obj}
 if(flag) obj_copy = 4;
 setState({...obj_copy))
```

Recently I came across the `?.` which is really helpful.

```
// we can change this
obj && obj.a === 'text' ? ... : ...

// into
obj?.a === 'text' ? ... : ...
```

I'm looking for something like above...
Just for knowledge purpose is there any way to do this?

Comment: is `flag` a boolean type?

Comment: The `obj?.x` syntax is called optional chaining operator and it "permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid". It has nothing to do with assigning and/or changing a value of a property inside of an object. The ternary operator is probably your best solution here without making things complicated for others and yourself in the future.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes flag type is boolean

Comment: @goto1 thanks for the info. I'm currently doing this via a ternary operator. I was just looking for another way of doing it.. If there is not other way, then I'll keep using same as you said.

Comment: @HarishSharma they are other ways, but it could get messy. If you really have a deeply nested object then you could perhaps utilize `lodash` and the `_.merge` function - `merge({a:{b:{c:{d: "Hello"}}}}, true ? {a:{b:{c:{d: "World"}}}} : {})`. See here https://lodash.com/docs/#merge

Comment: Understood. Thanks @goto1

Comment: what is the ?. operator called? It seems like a variation of the conditional ternary operator, but I couldn't find documentation for it online.

Comment: @MShakeG This is called **Optional chaining**. You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could a logical AND with the check and an object for spreading.

```js
let obj = { a: 4, b: 6 },
    flag = true;

console.log({ ...obj, ...flag === true && { a: 6 } });
flag = false;
console.log({ ...obj, ...flag === true && { a: 6 } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign` to conditionally assign the property like this:

```js
setState(Object.assign({ ...obj }, flag === true ? { a: 6 } : {}))
```

Moreover, if `flag` is a boolean or you can accept any truthy value, I'd remove the equals signs:

```js
setState(Object.assign({ ...obj }, flag ? { a: 6 } : {}))
```

Comment: The `object spread` operator is consistently faster than `Object.assign` and as per the question, I can do it with `spread` operator easily

Comment: Yes, I know. t was just an alternative to the 'nasty' use of ternary operator referencing the original object property that you wanted to avoid